# how to stop a loop in java if a value is incremented consecutively for three times?

Tags: java, loops, halt

i'm new to java. i'm writing a sample of rock paper scissors game. the user input 0,1,2 for rock, paper, scissors respectively. the program randomly generated the result. i almost managed to get it work but the only thing i'm stuck at is how to `STOP THE FOR LOOP IF ONE OF THE SIDE WINS CONSECUTIVELY FOR THREE TIMES`.

THIS IS THE ORIGINAL QUESTION

*Write a program that plays scissor-rock-paper game. The rule is that a scissor wins against a paper, a
rock wins against a scissor, and a paper wins against a rock. The program represent scissor as 0, rock
as 1, and paper as 2.
The game is to be played between the computer and a player. The program will prompt the user to
enter the number of rounds to win. For example, if the user enter 4 then the winner has to win at
least 3 out of the 4 rounds. If either party win 3 times consecutively, the game ends early without the
fourth round. If the user enter 5 rounds, the winner has to win at least 3 out of the 5 rounds. The
same rule of consecutive 3-wins also apply. After the user has entered the number of rounds, the
computer randomly generates a number between 0 and 2. The program then prompts the user to
enter a number 0, 1, or 2. After the last round (subject to the above mentioned early-winner-rule),
the program display a message indicating whether the computer or the user wins, loses, or draws.*

THIS IS MY CODE.

```
package assignment1;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class question1_9 {

// This program is used to play scissor-rock-paper game.

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random random = new Random();
        int scissor = 0, rock = 1, paper = 2, round, userinput,comprand, userresult = 0, compresult = 0, control,j,k;

        // Variables used in this program is declared and initialized.

        /* Number of rounds wished to be play are obtained from user. */

        System.out.println("WELCOME TO ROCK PAPER SCISSOR GAME. ");
        System.out.println("PLEASE ENTER THE NUMBER OF ROUND YOU WANT TO PLAY:  ");
        round = scan.nextInt();
        control = (round/2)+1;

        for(int i = 0; i<round; i++)
        {
            if (compresult == control | userresult == control)
            {
                break;
            }
            System.out.println("ROUND " + (i+1));
            System.out.println("PLEASE ENTER:\n 0 for scissor \n 1 for rock \n 2 for paper  \n");
            userinput = scan.nextInt();
            comprand = random.nextInt(3);
            if (userinput == 0)
            {
                if (comprand == 0)
                {
                    System.out.println("COMPUTER IS SCISSOR");
                    System.out.println("DRAW!!!");
                    i--;
                }
                else if (comprand == 1)
                {
                    System.out.println("COMPUTER IS ROCK");
                    System.out.println("COMPUTER WINS!!!");
                    compresult++;
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("COMPUTER IS PAPER");
                    System.out.println("YOU WIN!!!");
                    userresult++;
                }
                }
            else if (userinput == 1)
            {
                if (comprand == 0)
                {
                    System.out.println("COMPUTER IS SCISSOR");
                    System.out.println("COMPUTER WINS!!!");
                    compresult++;
                }
                else if (comprand == 1)
                {
                    System.out.println("COMPUTER IS ROCK");
                    System.out.println("YOU WIN!!!");
                    userresult++;
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("COMPUTER IS PAPER");
                    System.out.println("DRAW!!!");
                    i--;
                }
                }
            else
            {
                if (comprand == 0)
                {
                    System.out.println("COMPUTER IS SCISSOR");
                    System.out.println("YOU WIN!!!");
                    userresult++;
                }
                else if (comprand == 1)
                {
                    System.out.println("COMPUTER IS ROCK");
                    System.out.println("DRAW!!!");
                    i--;
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("COMPUTER IS PAPER");
                    System.out.println("COMPUTER WINS!!!");
                    compresult++;
                }
                }
            }
        if(compresult == userresult)
            System.out.println("\n\nFINAL RESULT IS DRAW!!!");
        else if (compresult > userresult)
            System.out.println("\n\nFINAL RESULT IS COMPUTER WIN!!!");
        else
            System.out.println("\n\nFINAL RESULT IS YOU WIN!!!");

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

use `break;` statement when you want to get out of current loop.

At top  of loop,

store the wins in an array

```
String[] results=new String[rounds];
```

store your results as "user" or "comp" for each round and at the end of loop do this

```
if((results[i].equals("user") && results[i-1].equals("user") && results[i-2].equals("user") || (results[i].equals("comp") && results[i-1].equals("comp") && results[i-2].equals("comp")))
{
break;
}
```

Comment: that is not true for all condtion. lets say there is 10 match, i win match no.2,4,6  , your solution will cause the loop to break even when it is not consecutive.

Comment: I understand . I have edited my answer just try this.

Answer (score 0):

Like shreyas said, use a `break` statement when you want to exit a loop.

I would set `compresult` to zero whenever the player wins a round, and set `userresult` to zero whenever the computer wins. Then, at the top of the loop, right after the `{` add:

```
if(userResult == 3 || computerResult == 3 || round/2 > 10)
{
    break;
}
```

Some code comes from shreyas's original [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29062252/4063725).

Comment: your solution would compromise another condition to win. what if both dont get three straight win and plays the game till the end?